# ruby -v says no such file or directory in mac os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I had the original ruby v2.6.8 I believe on my mac os. I wanted to upgrade to ruby 3.1.2 to get access to rails.

I installed ruby via homebrew, however I decided it woud be easier to manage using rbenv. I went to uninstall ruby via homebrew, and then instaled ruby 3.1.2 with rbenv.

Now when I use the

```
ruby -v 
-bash: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

using the command which ruby brings me this:

/Users/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby

So the ruby is there, and rbenv claims it installed ruby 3.1.2, but did homebrew install all of ruby including the version osx came with? Im pretty sure thats a yikes moment if it did. I also can't use any ruby commands under these circumstances so I don't really know what to do from here?

How do I get my $PATH to recognize the rbenv path to ruby as the global path? I'm on MacOs 11.3.1 BigSur if thats relevant.

Comment: just wondering if you have followed the setup instructions for rbenv to the "t" https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#using-package-managers ? there are some extra steps you need to take after you install it - namely, adding rbenv paths to the `PATH` envvar through your shell's settings (`~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` or whichever shell you are using)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the next steps to set up rbenv, and ruby 3.1.2.

**Step 1**

```
brew install rbenv
```

**Step 2** Add the following lines to your `.zshrc` file

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```

**Step 3**

```
brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build
```

**Step 4**

```
rbenv install 3.1.2
rbenv global 3.1.2
```